# Problem about a sequence; prove that $a_n=2^n$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

A sequence ${a_n}$ is defined recursively by $a_1 = 2$, $a_2 = 4$ and $a_n = a_{n−1} +2a_{n−2}$ for $n\geq 3$. Prove that $a_n = 2^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

I have this question and I'm not sure how to get started. I got the base case where $n=3$, both sides are $8$ so claim holds for base case, but as I get to the induction step, I have to prove that $a_n + 2(a_n-1) = 2^n+1$, and observing that $2^n + a_n + 2(a_n-1)$. This is where I'm stuck, i'm not sure how to possibly get this part to become $2^{n+1}$. Am i missing something completely obvious or what? Please help.

Comment: Did you mean that $a_n=a_{n-1}+2a_{\color{red}{n-2}}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.   Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: If $a_n=2^n$ and $a_{n-1}=2^{n-1}$, then $a_{n+1}=a_n+2a_{n-1}=2^n+2\cdot2^{n-1}=2^n+2^n=2\cdot2^n=2^{n+1}$

Comment: You have typos.  You aren't supposed to prove $a_n + 2(a_n -1) = 2^n +1$.  You are supposed to prove $a_n + 2a_{n-1}=2^{n+1}$ and .... that just falls out.  $a_n  = 2^n$ and $a_{n-1} = 2^{n-1}$ so $a_n + 2a_{n-1} = 2^n + 2\cdot 2^{n-1} = 2^{n+1}$.

Comment: "Am i missing something completely obvious or what? Please help."  Either you misread your  typo or you didn't realize you can use *strong* induction.  You don't just assume $a_n = 2^n$ but for all $k \le n$ that $a_k = 2^k$.  So $a_n = 2^n$ and $a_{n-1} = 2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use *strong* induction.  Instead of saying $P(n)$ is the statement that $a_n = 2^n$.  Use the statement $Q(n)$ which is the *stronger* statement:  for *all* natural numbers $k$ so that $k \le n$ then $a^k = 2^k$.

Base Case:  $n= 2$.

Now $a_1 = 2 = 2^1$ and $a_2 = 4 = 2^2$ so this true for all natural $k\le 2$.

Strong induction step:  Assume there is an $n$ so that for *all* $k \le n$ then $a_k = 2^k$.

The for $n+1$ we have $a_n = 2^n$ and $a_{n-1} = 2^{n-1}$ so $a_{n+1} = a_n + 2a_{n-1} = 2^n + 2\cdot 2^{n-1} = 2^n + 2^n =2\cdot 2^n = 2^{n+1}$.

And for all $k < n+1$ we had assume it was true for all $k \le n$.  It's still true for all those.